# The set of countable unions of half-open rectangles of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed under complementation.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is part of a solution to a problem from Rene Schilling's Measures, Integrals, and Martingales.

Here $\mathscr{T}$ is the set of all half open rectangles $[a_1,b_1) \times [a_2,b_2)\times \dots \times [a_n,b_n)$.

Set $\mathscr{K}:=\{A\subset \mathbb{R}^n : \exists (I_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathscr{T} : A=\cup_k I_k\}$ and observe that $I\in \mathscr{K} \implies I^c \in \mathscr{K}.$

It is not clear to me, nor can I prove that $I\in \mathscr{K} \implies I^c \in \mathscr{K}.$ I would greatly appreciate any help in showing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is true, not even when $n=1$.

Consider this example. Let $(a_k)$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$
and $b_n=a_k+2^{-k}$. Then $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty[a_k,b_k)$ has Lebesgue measure
$\le1$ and so is a proper subset of $\Bbb R$. But $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$
so its complement $A^c$ can contain no interval $[a,b)$.

Comment: I think you mean dense in $R$..